# MessageID format in WSE

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, web-services, wse

I've built a web service using WSE 3.0 that should interface with various other platforms like IBM's WebSphere. In the addressing part of the request the content of MessageID needs to be in the format uuid:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx. Anything else results in a "Bad Request" error. I've been told that according to WS-Addressing RFC MessageID can contain anything. Is there a way to allow a MessagdID that doesn't conform to that format?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory: I think the MessageID in WSE is a URI. I guess you can try with any string that has a URL moniker (http, ftp etc) and a string after that.

Comment: Any kind of format is troublesome since the client has his own in house format.

Comment: Then you have tough luck. WS-Addressing states that the Message ID is a URI.

"A URI that uniquely identifies this message in time and space. No two messages with a distinct application intent may share a [message id] property." ... snip ... "The value of this property is an opaque URI whose interpretation beyond equivalence is not defined in this specification."

See: http://www.w3.org/Submission/ws-addressing/#_Toc77464322

Comment: Thanks for that link. I always suspected this, but having an official ruling on it would definitely help in convincing the other party. Thanks again.